# Different results for SecTrustEvaluate for one certificate for different policies

Tags: xcode, afnetworking

I don't understand in what circumstances below situation happening (piece of code from AFSecurityPolicy.m, AFPublicKeyForCertificate function, AFNetwork Framework):

```
policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
AF_Require_noErr(SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(tempCertificates, policy, &allowedTrust), _out);
AF_Require_noErr(SecTrustEvaluate(allowedTrust, &result), _out);
//result = 5 (kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure)

//different policy
policy = SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"www.MySite.com");
AF_Require_noErr(SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(tempCertificates, policy, &allowedTrust), _out);
AF_Require_noErr(SecTrustEvaluate(allowedTrust, &result), _out);
//result = 4 (kSecTrustResultUnspecified)
```

Certificate is valid and not expired. Signature algorithm SHA-1. Don't get why it return **kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure** and not **kSecTrustResultUnspecified** for **SecPolicyCreateBasicX509**.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Apple's documentation for Certificate, Key, and Trust Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecTrustEvaluate)

> The SecTrustEvaluate function validates a certificate by verifying its signature plus the signatures of the certificates in its certificate chain, up to the anchor certificate, according to the policy or policies included in the trust management object.
>
> As a rule, you should handle the various return values as follows:
>
> - `kSecTrustResultUnspecified`—Evaluation successfully reached an (implicitly trusted) anchor certificate without any evaluation failures, but never encountered any explicitly stated user-trust preference. This is the most common return value.
> - `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure`—This means that you should not trust the chain as-is, but that the chain could be trusted with some minor change to the evaluation context, such as ignoring expired certificates or adding an additional anchor to the set of trusted anchors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think you didn't get what i mean. SecPolicyCreateSSL is stronger then SecPolicyCreateBasicX509 because do what x509 do and also do host name verification. But i don't get why stronger policy evaluate well and weaker policy no.

Comment: Hello Matt, can you point me to any resource for better understanding how to manage kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure return code for trust evaluation of a certificate chain? In particular I can't understand how to verify if a certificate is expired (and which one is in the chain) and eventually ignore it.